# Webservice for getting share holding patterns for an Indian Stock

Tags: api, web-services, stock

I am looking for the webservices that will give me share holding patterns of promoters/FIIs/Retail investors for a stocks on BSE/NSE?

Note: Please find below a stock for sample.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time looking for a similar service. to my knowledge, only Qunadl was providing one. when I reached out them I got a response -

*Thank you very much for reaching out.
We are no longer accepting new subscriptions for this data, as per our agreement with the original publisher of this data. At this time, we do not have another similar database to this on Quandl. I'm sorry we cannot be of more help in this regard.*

so looks like there is none in Indian market for now.